# Unable to delete items from react material-ui data grid list, what could be the issue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a basic list of customers. I am using material UI DataGrid to render the list. Although each list has the buttons to edit and delete the item. But I'm unable to delete the item from the list even though when I tried to console I got the specific id of the customer.
***Here is the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-chatelet-rsoes?file=/src/components/CustomerList.js) to my complete code in codesandbox.***

**CustomerList.js (I've highlighted my code with comments so you can easily jump to that specific area)**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Button, Grid, Typography, Box } from "@material-ui/core";
import { DataGrid } from "@material-ui/data-grid";
import { useStyles } from "./CustomerListStyle";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import DialogActions from "@material-ui/core/DialogActions";
import DialogContent from "@material-ui/core/DialogContent";
import DialogContentText from "@material-ui/core/DialogContentText";
import DialogTitle from "@material-ui/core/DialogTitle";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

// my initial data which I'm passing to state names customers
const customerData = [
  { id: 1, name: "Customer 1", gender: "Male", email: "user@gmail.com" },
  { id: 2, name: "Customer 2", gender: "Male", email: "user@gmail.com" },
  { id: 3, name: "Customer 3", gender: "Female", email: "user@gmail.com" }
];

const CustomerList = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [customers, setCustomers] = React.useState(customerData);
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("");
  const [gender, setGender] = React.useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");

  // just to render MUI DataGrid
  const columns = [
    { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 70 },
    { field: "name", headerName: "Name", width: 200 },
    {
      field: "gender",
      headerName: "Gender",
      width: 150
    },
    {
      field: "email",
      headerName: "Email",
      description: "This column has a value getter and is not sortable.",
      width: 250
    },
    {
      field: "action",
      headerName: "Action",
      width: 250,

      // Important: passing id from customers state so I can delete or edit each user
      renderCell: (id) => (
        <>
          <Button
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "#ffcc00",
              marginRight: 40,
              padding: "3px 35px"
            }}
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            type="submit"
          >
            Edit
          </Button>

          <Button
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "#e8605d",
              padding: "3px 35px"
            }}
            onClick={() => handleDelete(id)}
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            type="submit"
          >
            Delete
          </Button>
        </>
      )
    }
  ];

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  // Issue: not deleting the row from table
  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    setCustomers(customers.filter((user) => user.id !== id));
    console.log(id);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.value);
    const newCustomer = {
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 999),
      name: name,
      gender: gender,
      email: email
    };
    setCustomers([...customers, newCustomer]);
    console.log(`user data is ${newCustomer}`);
    console.log(customers);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Grid
        container
        direction="row"
        justify="center"
        alignItems="center"
        className={classes.listHeader}
      >
        <Grid item md={8}></Grid>

        <Grid item md={4}>
          <Button
            className={classes.btn}
            onClick={handleClickOpen}
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            type="submit"
          >
            Add New Customer
          </Button>

          <Dialog
            disableBackdropClick
            open={open}
            onClose={handleClose}
            aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
          >
            <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Add New Customer</DialogTitle>
            <form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <DialogContent>
                <TextField
                  value={name}
                  onChange={(event) => setName(event.target.value)}
                  autoFocus
                  margin="dense"
                  id="name"
                  label="Name"
                  type="text"
                  fullWidth
                />
                <TextField
                  value={gender}
                  onChange={(event) => setGender(event.target.value)}
                  margin="dense"
                  id="gender"
                  label="Gender"
                  type="text"
                  fullWidth
                />
                <TextField
                  value={email}
                  onChange={(event) => setEmail(event.target.value)}
                  margin="dense"
                  id="email"
                  label="Email Address"
                  type="email"
                  fullWidth
                />
              </DialogContent>
              <DialogActions>
                <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
                  Cancel
                </Button>
                <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary" type="submit">
                  Add
                </Button>
              </DialogActions>
            </form>
          </Dialog>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>

      <div className={classes.customerList}>
        <DataGrid
          rows={customers}
          columns={columns}
          pageSize={5}
          checkboxSelection={false}
          disableSelectionOnClick={true}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default CustomerList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are calling `id` in `handleDelete` is not the id, it is a customer object.  Replace it with something like

```
  const handleDelete = (clickedUser) => {
    setCustomers(customers.filter((user) => user.id !== clickedUser.id));
    console.log(clickedUser.id);
  };
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't realize that it was an object. Thanks it worked now

Answer (score 0):

- You are not forwarding "id" into "onClick" event

```js
 <Button
      style={{
              backgroundColor: "#e8605d",
              padding: "3px 35px"
            }}
            onClick={() => handleDelete(id)}  // here
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            type="submit"
          >
            Delete
          </Button>
```

- I should be onClick={(id) => handleDelete(id)}

Comment: I appreciate your efforts but the issue was in handleDelete method which I fixed with help of @possum.

Answer (score 0):

@possums 's solution (quite) works, you have to stop mouse event propagation to avoid `No row with id # found` exception.

Replace the delete button with:

```js
          <Button
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "#e8605d",
              padding: "3px 35px"
            }}
            onClick={(e) => {
                      e.stopPropagation()
                      handleDelete(id)
               }
            }
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            type="submit"
          >
            Delete
          </Button>
```

and keep the delete handler has suggested

```js
  const handleDelete = (clickedUser) => {
    setCustomers(customers.filter((user) => user.id !== clickedUser.id));
    console.log(clickedUser.id);
  };
```